Convert Geopotential Height's Unit from $m^2 s^{-2}$ to hPa
Can someone please explain how to convert geopotential height 500 hPa from ERA5, where units while plotting are displayed as m2 s-2?

The geopotential is the work (force x distance) required to bring a 1kg object to a certain height. The units of work are $kg \frac {m^2}{s^2}$ Dividing by the unit mass gives the work per kilogram which is the geopotential $\Phi$ and has units of $\frac {m^2}{s^2}$
The geopotential height Z is:
$$Z = \frac {\Phi} g$$ where $g = 9.8 m/s^2$
You need the hypsometric equation to convert to pressure:
$$Z_2 − Z_1 =\frac {RT}{g} \ln\frac {p_1} {p_2}$$
or
$$\frac{p_1}{p_2}= e^{\frac g {RT}(Z_2-Z_1)}$$
Where R is the gas constant and T is temperature. Z is the geopotential height. $Z_1 = 0$ at mean sea level.
Hope this was helpful.
Note there are integral forms for this that can be used to account for g varying with height.
https://geo.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Meteorology_and_Climate_Science/Practical_Meteorology_(Stull)/01%3A_Atmospheric_Basics/1.07%3A_Atmospheric_Structure
https://www.chemeurope.com/en/encyclopedia/Hypsometric_equation.html
